# How to create animation like Apple Music app

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I want to create a view with lot of button in circle shape but want them arrange and animate like Apple music app as shown below, I can not post image you can view screenshot [here](http://www.imore.com/apple-music-faq)  one with red bubbles

Comment: Didn't somebody ask the same question a few days ago?

Comment: I can not find one, you can share link if its already asked

Comment: I have been easily able to find it by searching for [objective-c] apple music.  -1 for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not adding full code because there are number of things done, but here are the steps you can follow to create something similar.

You can create round button by setting there `cornerRadius = height/2` provided both height and width are same, to make them scrollable add them in a scrollView and set `contentSize` of scrollView. You can add scaling animation to the each button i.e add `CAKeyFrameAnimation`for `key path` `transform.scale.y` and `transform.scale.x`

We can also do this by using spritKit [here](https://github.com/CoderXpert/AnimatedMenuPool) is the component which do similar